# Help in ICMP spoofing

Tags: c, security

I wanted to learn this concept as per course syllabus. I need some idea to do the ICMP spoofing. I found the ICMP spoofing program online but I have to do something like this: When a host pings an unknown ip address whether it exists or not there has to be echo reply packet making the unknown host alive for the person who is pinging. How do I achieve this.

Can someone help me with this concept what I can do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually difficult (but not impossible) to achieve. Your spoofing server has to be able to listen to all traffic on the network to be able to receive the pings that are not intended to go to itself. This is typically not the case on a switched network, but can be worked around, for example via [MAC Flooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_flooding), or by connecting your spoofing server to a [monitoring port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) on your switch.

You can probably find a lot of informations on the [Ping page](http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage.htm).

***Edit***:

So, your spoofing server has to listen to all ICMP ECHO REQUEST trafic, and generate an appropriate response. You could also have a look at [packETH](http://packeth.sourceforge.net/), which is a tool that can generate those packets.

Comment: I read the topics you have given but I didn't understand the way to call a ICMP server. Every where they have given the ICMP spoofing for a client. In the UNIX programming text book the author had given a short version of the ping program. I am not able to understand what I am supposed to do. I am totally confused.